Do binaries elevated with an UAC Bypass technique have the UAC Bypass as an ancestor process?
I've successfully elevated a binary (in this case, cmd.exe) using a UAC bypass technique, and I'm trying to determine if it's possible to trace the elevated binary back to the "elevator" program. The specific UAC bypass technique I used involves the ICMLuaUtil COM interface
My question is: after elevating the binary, is it possible to identify the original process that initiated the elevation? If this technique doesn't leave traces that would allow this, I'm also curious if other more well-known UAC bypass methods, such as the fodhelper technique (described here: Fodhelper UAC Bypass), would allow the elevated binary to be traced back to the bypassing program.
I made this little program which tracks process ids for me :
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// Function to get the process path by process ID
const char* GetProcessPathById(DWORD processId) {
    static char processPath[MAX_PATH];
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processId);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return "Unknown";

    if (GetModuleFileNameExA(hProcess, NULL, processPath, sizeof(processPath))) {
        // Convert to lowercase
        std::transform(processPath, processPath + strlen(processPath), processPath, ::tolower);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return processPath;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return "Unknown";
}

// Function to get the parent process ID of a given process ID
DWORD GetParentProcessId(DWORD pid) {
    DWORD ppid = (DWORD)-1;
    HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (DWORD)-1;

    PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { 0 };
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    if (Process32First(h, &pe)) {
        do {
            if (pe.th32ProcessID == pid) {
                ppid = pe.th32ParentProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(h, &pe));
    }

    CloseHandle(h);
    return ppid;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    DWORD targetPid;

    // Check if a process ID was provided as a command-line argument
    if (argc > 1) {
        targetPid = std::stoul(argv[1]); // Convert the argument to DWORD
    } else {
        targetPid = GetCurrentProcessId(); // Use the current process ID if none provided
    }

    DWORD currentPid = targetPid;

    std::cout << "Process Ancestry for PID: " << targetPid << std::endl;

    while (currentPid != (DWORD)-1) {
        const char* processPath = GetProcessPathById(currentPid);
        std::cout << "Process ID: " << currentPid << " - Path: " << processPath << std::endl;

        DWORD parentPid = GetParentProcessId(currentPid);
        if (parentPid == currentPid) {
            break; // Avoid an infinite loop in case of a self-referencing process
        }
        currentPid = parentPid;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


After elevating the binary with the COM interface technique, here is the output I got :
Process Ancestry for PID: 17244
Process ID: 17244 - Path: (the exe path)
Process ID: 7924 - Path: c:\windows\syswow64\dllhost.exe
Process ID: 520 - Path: Unknown
Process ID: 888 - Path: Unknown
Process ID: 760 - Path: Unknown
Process ID: 616 - Path: Unknown

I assume that 616's parent process is the system process and thus, it's not traced to the elevator program ?

Use OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION) and QueryFullProcessImageName() to avoid access denied errors. Alternatively, just run TaskManager to see the process paths or run ProcMon to see the process creation events.

@Luke What technique are you talking about ? Fodhelper ? If that's the case, I'm not getting denied access in the first place. Nor with the ICMLuaUtil technique. I'm just wondering if I can have my elevated binary as a descendant process of my UAC Bypass binary

I mean so you can actually see the names of the processes instead of "Unknown". If you want to set your parent process programmatically you can use InitializeProcThreadAttributeList() and friends.

@Luke I was able to see more processes, but those are all window processes : main.exe => dllhost.exe => svchost.exe => services.exe => wininit.exe => unknown => system process. I believe I would need to change the UAC Bypass code to see conclusive results.
